# How to set a cell value to zero if checkbox is checked

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, checkbox, nested-if

I have a sheet I and I want to have the values in one row be set to zero once the corresponding checkbox is clicked. Here is what my sheet looks like(https://postimg.cc/CBDdYsjN), I want each cell in column E to be set to zero when its same row checkbox in col A is set to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try in F2:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A=TRUE; 0; E2:E))
```

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise:

***F2***

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E2:E="","",NOT(A2:A)*E2:E))
```

If you customize checkbox and invert True and False, you don't need `NOT`